# How to print special characters like ñ in Bluetooth Printer on Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am using Nteumm XL-1800A 58mm printer. I can't figure out how to print the "ñ". It always print's chinise character's. This is my code for printing the output, I already added a line of codes to try to remove the chinise character and by using the ISO-8859-1 and still nothing.

```
 mOutputStream.write(0x1C); mOutputStream.write(0x2E); //Removal of chinise characters
 mOutputStream.write(myString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
```

Comment: post the code which prints the string

Comment: code added @3iL

Comment: try this: outStream.write(EncodingUtils.getBytes(yourString, "ISO-8859-1"));

Comment: EncodingUtils doesn't recognize @3iL

Comment: I can't find any solution :/

Comment: Have you tries UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1?

Comment: yes, and i think it is also a default encoding conversion of a characters @3iL

Answer (score 0):

you're using wrong encoding for ñ. Encoding of ñ in UTF-8 is 0xC3 0xB1 . Check this [link](http://graphemica.com/%C3%B1).

Answer (score 0):

You should set latin table code before by writing this bytes:

0x1b, 0x74, 0x12

In your example:

```
mOutputStream.write(0x1b); 
mOutputStream.write(0x74);
mOutputStream.write(0x12);
mOutputStream.write(myString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
```

Hope that helpes

Comment: It seems my thermal printer is not support for this. I cannot try it anymore, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
outputStream.write(0x1C);
outputStream.write(0x2E); //cancel character chinnese
outputStream.write(0x1B);
outputStream.write(0x74);
outputStream.write(0x10);

outputStream.write(myString.getBytes("iso-8859-1"));
```